# External Data Source own webservice

Tags: java

[TASK]
Salesforce integration with external database (e.g. PostgreSQL)

[GOAL]
Integration without using external system e.g. Informatica, Lightning connect

[TO DO]
Build own webservice (Java). 
Connect to External Data Source in Salesforce.

[PROBLEM]
1. I am a junior developer and I don't sure how begin this task. 

2. Why I haven't in External Data Source type OData ? I have only -None- and Simply URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OData external data source in Salesforce is a part of Lightning Connect and has extra licensing costs. Speak to your AE about enablement.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Tell me please, I can connect to my database (external) through Type: Simply URL ? 
If yes, what I should doing ?
If no, I understand that I should buy extra licence. Yes ?

Comment: The Simple URL connector is just for files sharing and will not let you connect to an external database. If you want to use native external objects, you will need to pay a license fee for Lightning Connect. You could also write your own integration using standard SObjects, but that is significantly more code and work. You may wish to speak with a technical architect about your specific integration needs.

Comment: Ok, In your opinion Rest API is good way to my task ?
I want to try coding own integration.